# Using Modifier Functions after the op:reduce() Function in an Optic Access Plan

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

Is it possible to use optic modifier functions like `op:group-by()`, `op:where()`, etc. after running the `op:reduce()` function? I haven't been able to find anything in the [Optic API Dev Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI) regarding this question. We have some data stored in TDEs that contains an effective date. At query time we pass an `op:where()` filter to find rows that are active and "in effect" so to speak. For the "parent" it is technically possible to have two rows "in effect". The business requirement for this case is to get the first row after sorting the rows by the effective date in descending order (i.e. get the most recent "in effect").

I'm not aware of a way to force a join operation to only use the first matching row from the right plan onto the left plan. My current "hack" to implement this is to perform my filters, joins, and sorting followed by the `op:reduce()` function to iterate through the rows and check if the previous row was for the same parent. If it is the same parent, then I set the "isFirst" flag to `fn:false()`, otherwise `fn:true()`. I then pass the `op:result()` of that reduction into the `op:from-literals()` to perform the aggregations and counts I need to on the "first" rows.

Here is pseudocode of this "hacky" implementation:

```
let $reducePlan := $mainPlan
    => op:reduce(function($previous as map:map*, $row as map:map) as map:map* {
            let $prevUuid := map:get($previous[fn:last()], "parentUuid")
            let $currUuid := map:get($row, "parentUuid")
            let $isFirst := 
                if ($prevUuid eq $currUuid)
                then fn:false()
                else fn:true()
            let $_ := map:put($row, "isFirst", $isFirst)
            return (
                $previous, 
                $row
            )
        },
        map:map()
    )
    => op:result()

let $literals := op:from-literals($reducePlan)
    (: Get the "first" row for each parent :)
    => op:where(op:eq(op:col("isFirst"), fn:true()))
    (:
        Other aggregations and counts here...
    :)
    => op:result()
return $literals
```

This produces correct results but I worry about its performance when there are lots of parents and overall hacky approach. I would normally use the `op:group-by()` function but I need to perform aggregations on other columns that may not all be the same value. I am not able to change the format or structure of the XML that produces the view.

Two main questions:

1. Is there a way to limit a join to the first matching row or limit the right plan before the join to only have the first row for a "parent"?
2. Can I change something about the way I perform the `op:reduce()` to leave the optic plan in place to be able to run additional modifier functions afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything after you no longer have a valid plan is post-processing and would not scale.  `op:reduce()` piped into `op:from-literals()` effectively inhales all of the content from indexes, and into memory.

I would suggest that you take an approach that continues to modify plans.  For your use-case, if the effectiveDate is unique per parentUuid, then an approach could be: make a plan that isolates the appropriate timestamp per parentUuid and then use that to filter the results.

Example below does the following:

- Generate ~60,000 records (using 3 unique parentUUids at random and a random status for inEffect)
- In the middle of those, plant the newest records that are also currently inEffect = true

  ```
   xquery version "1.0-ml";

   import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic"
        at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";

   let $parentUuid-list := ("aa-bb-cc", "dd-ee-ff", "gg-hh-ii")

   let $fake-view := op:from-literals((
     for $parentUuid at $step in $parentUuid-list
        let $base := $step * 10000
        for $y in (1 to 9999)
          let $id := $base + $y
          return map:entry("id", $id)=>map:with("parentUuid", $parentUuid)=>map:with("inEffect", xdmp:random(3) = 1)=>map:with("effectiveDateTime", fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("PT" || xdmp:random(99999999) || "S")),
     map:entry("id", 40001)=>map:with("parentUuid", "aa-bb-cc")=>map:with("inEffect", fn:true())=>map:with("effectiveDateTime", fn:current-dateTime()),
     map:entry("id", 40002)=>map:with("parentUuid", "dd-ee-ff")=>map:with("inEffect", fn:true())=>map:with("effectiveDateTime", fn:current-dateTime()),
     map:entry("id", 40003)=>map:with("parentUuid", "gg-hh-ii")=>map:with("inEffect", fn:true())=>map:with("effectiveDateTime", fn:current-dateTime()),
     for $parentUuid at $step in $parentUuid-list
        let $base := ($step * 9999) + 40000
        for $y in (1 to 9999)
          let $id := $base + $y
          return map:entry("id", $id)=>map:with("parentUuid", $parentUuid)=>map:with("inEffect", xdmp:random(3) = 1)=>map:with("effectiveDateTime", fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("PT" || xdmp:random(99999999) || "S"))

   ))

   let $filter-plan := $fake-view
     =>op:where(op:eq(op:col("inEffect"), fn:true()))
     =>op:group-by(op:col("parentUuid"), op:max(op:col("maxDate"), op:col("effectiveDateTime")))

   let $result-plan := $fake-view
   => op:exists-join(
       $filter-plan, 
       op:on(op:col("parentUuid"),op:col("parentUuid")),
       op:eq(op:col("maxDate"), op:col("effectiveDateTime"))
     )


   return  $result-plan  => op:result()
  ```

The end result is that the three expected records are shown.
[image]

The key here is in the filter-plan. It looks like this:

[image]

Those 2 columns are enough to then use a filtering join.

This may not be exactly what you need. However, by creating keys in a certain way and ensuring that there is something unique for the aggregate makes this a pattern I use often with optic

Comment: Hi @David, this is exactly what I was looking for. I need to modify my plan a little bit but this will work. Thanks for the sample as well - very easy to understand and follow!

Comment: Woohoo! Glad it put you in the right direction.  -David